# How can I create JSX elements from an array of React-Icon names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

```
import React from "react"
import {GiCard2Spades,GiCard3Spades} from "react-icons/gi"
    
const x = ["GiCard8Spades","GiCard9Spade"]
const y = x.map(item => <item />) //basically to get <GiCard8Spades /> elements
return(<div>{y}</div>)
```

I know I can right away make array manually with JSX items like  but need other way at this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dead set on using strings, you could try

```
import * as Icons from "react-icons/gi"

const x = ["GiCard8Spades","GiCard9Spade"];
return(<div>{x.map((item) => Icons[item])}</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```js
    import React from "react"
    import {GiCard2Spades,GiCard3Spades} from "react-icons/gi"
        
    const x = [GiCard8Spades,GiCard9Spade];
    return(<div>{x.map(item => item)}</div>)//basically to get <GiCard8Spades /> elements
```

This way you will create an array of JSX.Elements, not an array of strings

Comment: probably the variable x, is from an database an james save the names of the icons.

Comment: if that's the case they can try to import the whole library and use the string as key

```javascript

    import React from "react"
    import * as ReactIcons from "react-icons/gi"
        
    const x = ["GiCard8Spades", "GiCard9Spade"];
    return(<div>{x.map(item => ReactIcons[item])}</div>)
```

It may solve the problem, but take a look into import cost

Answer (score 0):

Yea Im kinda stupid, should just used

```
import React from "react"
import {GiCard2Spades,GiCard3Spades} from "react-icons/gi"
    
const x = [GiCard8Spades,GiCard9Spades]
const y = x.map(item => React.createElement(item))
return(<div>{y}</div>)
```